# Moving torrents to new Windows: uTorrent

Tags: utorrent

Eventually my hard drive crashed, but I saved Users folder (Win7). Now what's the easiest way to have same torrents on new Windows, but with different root folder for Downloads? I've read `Migrating Your Files to µTorrent` article but couldn't find how to extract all my previous data from Users folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There should be a folder at %APPDATA%\roaming\utorrent which contains all the torrents along with the state-information & settings that utorrent needs. Migrate that from your backup and you should be good to go.

EDIT: Corrected folder path

Comment: It's under `%APPDATA%\Roaming\uTorrent`, to be exact. :)

Comment: Well, the more important thing is how to patch all those files easily in order to reflect new download folder? Or patch the .dat files.

Comment: Perhaps you can just move the torrent files that you need and add the entire directory manually after setting the default download directory.

That is assuming that the downloads aren't in progress, that would complicate the matter somewhat I guess.

Comment: Say if I have 1700 torrents, which are partially single file data and partially folders then I have to manually go through each torrent and set new directory? Where the directory information is saved, in torrent file or in dat file?

Comment: The Directory information would be saved in the .dat file. The torrent file only has information about the download (trackers, files that are downloaded, size etc).